# Does the "accept and store credit cards" part of PayPal's REST API require an Advanced or Pro product?

Tags: api, rest, paypal

I've always been super confused when it comes to mapping between PayPal's APIs (both "Classic" and the new REST APIs) and the actual PayPal business products (the account level ones seem to be Standard, Advanced, and Pro; there's also Payflow Link and Payflow Pro which acts as a gateway; and then Express Checkout which seems to straddle everything).

Specifically, do the ["accept and store credit card"](https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/integration/direct/accept-credit-cards/) bits of the REST API require an Payments Advanced or Payments Pro account (the ones that require a monthly fee), or is any standard business PayPal account eligible to use them?

Answer (score 1):

For anyone else running across this, it looks like a **Payments Pro** account is required.

> Accepting credit card payments via Rest API's would need a pro account. Please let me know your contact information, if you're interested to have a pro account. One of our sales executives would reach out to you.

Comment: Thanks for updating with an answer based on your findings. On a related note could you please look at [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23744646/is-paypal-rest-api-stable-and-out-of-beta) question? My Paypal sales rep is pushing me to use the classic API and not the REST API.