# Is paypal REST API stable and out of beta?

Tags: paypal

I have looked at the [Paypal REST API](https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/api/) and at [classic API](https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/classic/api/). I like the Direct card processing support the REST API offers and the ability to use the Vault from the REST API.

Only problem is our PayPal sales rep **insists** the REST APIs are not stable and should not be used and wants us to use **PayPal payments Pro** with [this Class API](https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/classic/paypal-payments-pro/integration-guide/WPWebsitePaymentsPro/) .

We have a business account and only expect to receive payments in the US, which per [this](https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/integration/direct/rest_api_payment_country_currency_support/#direct-credit-card-payments) link should be supported just fine. We need to accept payments using a mobile app and website. The mobile app needs to support one time transactions and both (app and website) need to support transactions using stored credit card information (which is where the Vault feature seems really handy).

I clearly see a lot of REST API questions so now doubt its in use.

Question for devs using the REST API over the past 6 months:

- has it changed in a breaking manner for you?
- Is it reasonably available (99.9%) for your applications?
- Does using the Vault REST API feature require a Payments Pro account?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The RESTful APIs would work for you based off of what you stated. Granted they are not to parity with the Classic APIs just yet but the features you were requesting (Direct Card and Vault) are good to go.  Pro is not required for Vault with a US account.

Lastly, without knowing the full conversation you had with your Sales Rep, I can't comment on why they felt so strongly against the RESTful APIs.  However, if you open up a ticket at www.paypal.com/mts with all of your integration requirements, we can help you out with the best options available.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15405632/paypal-rest-api-adaptive-multiple-payments-change-payee